# MySQL SELECT rows WHERE time is within a specified time window

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL database with the column `event_time` with timestamps in this format: 2012-07-18 12:54:45.

I need to select any rows that fall into a specified time window e.g. 0700 to 1159. How can I do a SELECT that fetches those rows for any date?

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM dataset WHERE event_time >= "07:00" AND <= "11:59"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to extract time from timestamp:

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM dataset 
WHERE TIME(event_time) BETWEEN "07:00" AND "11:59"
```

or

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM dataset 
WHERE cast(event_time as time) BETWEEN "07:00" AND "11:59"
```

Both of them work totally fine for me! Hope my answer help you with your question.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I can cast the datetime column to TIME, and then do a BETWEEN.

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM dataset
WHERE TIME(event_time) BETWEEN "07:00"
AND "11:59"
```